# How to go about inserting rediscovered backup files in a git repo

Tags: git

My problem is that I have a fairly large set of "brute force versioned" files, i.e. stored along with date indicator, that are also distributed over various data carriers.

After having overcome my aversion against version control, I would like to put all those files in a git repo that allows for chronological reconstruction of the snapshots.

Questions:

- suppose I have a git repo that contains snapshots corresponding to dates **A** <- **B** <- **E** <- **F** in chronological order and I discover snaphot **C** on a dustcovered data carrier; how do I go about adding spapshot **C** to resemble the git repo contain **A** <- **B** <- **C** <- **E** <- **F**
- how can I add a file *f* to snapshot **B** that is already present in the other submitted snapshots?

Ideally the generated git repo should give the impression that all submissions happened in chronological order, i.e. at some point, when I'm sure that everything is in the repo, I want to remove all information about the order in which the snapshots/files have been added to the git repo; is there also a solution for that?

As I am no git wizzard I would appreciate hands on solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to splice a commit C into the middle of the history after B:

1. Make a branch name to hold your place, and check it out.
2. Reset to B.
3. Add the newly discovered files and commit them as C.
4. *Rebase* the old branch on top of the new branch.

---

Here's an example. I've prepared a sample repo; here's the log:

```
commit 740dc8c1dd312d93c63f8edd4dfb91503f7f66df (HEAD -> master)

    F

 F (new) | 0
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)

commit d0b2924ad33e4d7f2898eb8707bbdf016f7adf8a

    E

 E (new) | 0
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)

commit a932a794ceb6df01483490410d7a3e538f556876

    B

 B (new) | 0
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)

commit 85d3a01ee94427729b745078c8c06d8b89a6af52

    A

 A (new) | 0
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

So, reading from the bottom up, I added file A and called that commit A, added file B and called that commit B, then the same for E and for F.

Now pretend we discover the existence of file C. I'll splice into the chain of history a commit that adds C:

```
git branch holdMyPlace
git checkout holdMyPlace
git reset --hard a932a794 # go back to B
touch C
git add .
git commit -m"C"
git rebase holdMyPlace master
```

Here's the log now:

```
commit 882d6e170101a1a9cb0462c5eb1b6103470ab07c (HEAD -> master)

    F

 F (new) | 0
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)

commit 57e9a01b94f48741b70ecfea32492659cef4aeb3

    E

 E (new) | 0
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)

commit c5b41b74b2dc0a36bef17c01ed581eda585ce103 (holdMyPlace)

    C

 C (new) | 0
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)

commit a932a794ceb6df01483490410d7a3e538f556876

    B

 B (new) | 0
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)

commit 85d3a01ee94427729b745078c8c06d8b89a6af52

    A

 A (new) | 0
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

That is exactly the history you wanted: it looks like C was added after B, and E and F were added after C.